# Copy all values from fields in one class to another class

Tags: java

I have 2 classes:

```
public class A {
  Integer a;
  X object;
  List<Y> list;
}
 
public class B {
 Integer a;
  X object;
  List<Y> list;
}
```

Cloud you tell me how to copy fields from class A to B
Is it a good idea to use Gson?  are there better solutions ?

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
String tmp = gson.toJson(a);
B b = gson.fromJson(tmp,B.class);
```

Comment: There is a third party library called BeanUtils from Apache Commons that will handle this using copyProperties(A, B).

Comment: There is also [`MapStruct`](https://mapstruct.org/) which is basically a Java bean mapper, a mapper interface needs to be created to allow mapping of the two classes.  [Quick Guide at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)

Comment: "Magic" copying always adds a performance penalty. Java reflection is slow. There still is _code generation_ generating a `copy(()` automatically, possibly even on byte code level.

Answer (score 0):

The most oop method is to add a constructor to each of the classes that gets the other class and copies the fields needed.

Comment: Then you'd have tight coupling between `A` and `B` which you might not want

Comment: @QBrute no, you do. Names of fields are not unique and fields are private to boot. The alternative to tight coupling is conflating namespaces (i.e. shooting someone to death because got a `public interface Gun {void shoot(Person p);}` and decided to just sort of slapdash that into fitting `public interface Camera {void shoot(Person p);}`), and/or breaking private API which has similarly dire consequences. Tight coupling is far less bad.

Comment: If you assume that all of the fields match between two classes, those classes are already tightly coupled. You can’t change one without changing the other. The difference is whether the tight coupling is explicit and checked by the compiler vs. implicit and likely to fail at runtime.